# Can I travel to EU country after resigning in Germany?

Tags: germany, blue-card, sweden, denmark

I have resigned from my job in Berlin, Germany. Now I am on notice period. I am planning to do Abmeldung now. So, after doing Abmeldung and after notice period expires, can I travel to an EU country(specifically Denmark/Sweden) for couple of days. This link https://www.eu-bluecard.com/faq/ says I can stay in Germany for 3 months after resignation, don't know I can travel or not. The reason for going to Denmark/Sweden is that my return flight is from Denkmark (and I will stay 1 day in Sweden)

Comment: Will you have to surrender your residence permit? If the residence permit stays valid for three more months, I don't see any problem. If you get some sort of other temporary document, that could be an issue.

Comment: I don't know what will happen during Abmeldung. Will they surrender?

Comment: I don't know, in principle the Abmeldung is a local formality, not necessarily related to your residence permit (Germans have to do it too when moving). Have you received instructions to surrender your permit?

Comment: I havent recieved any instruction. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Just to add what happens with me. I traveled even after resignation. In short, just make sure blue card is valid then you can travel.